# Automator keeps using numbers in exponential form

Tags: applescript, automator

I created this code that should launch whatsapp with a specific number in clipboard:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set text1 to the clipboard
        set text2 to 1 - text1 as real
        do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & 1 - text2
    return input
end run
```

*

> The subtractions are added to copy the correct number into the form

*

However, the phone number is stated in an exponential form which gives an error.

```
Example: 0501234567
Expected Output: 971501234567
Actual  Output : 9715.01234567E+8
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an XY-problem probably. The real question is: How do I strip off a leading 0 of a telephone number to get it to work with the whatsapp API in an Apple Script/Automator.

Comment: If you have `0501234567` on `the clipboard` and your goal is to open this **URL** `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971501234567"`, then simply, `do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & text 2 thru -1 of (the clipboard as string)` should do it. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and fast way requires to install a scripting edition [Satimage.osax](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) ([direct d/l](http://www.satimage.fr/software/downloads/Satimage411.pkg)) and works with regex. The certificate of the pkg sadly expired!

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set text1 to change "^0+" into "" in (the clipboard as string) with regexp
    do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & text1
    return input
end run
```

`^0+` strips off leading zeros!

---

A second one with *sed* **but no additional installs**:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set text1 to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (the clipboard as string) & " | sed 's/^0*//'"
    do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & text1
    return input
end run
```

- `quoted form of (the clipboard as string)`: '0501234567'
- `do shell script "echo " & '0501234567' & " | sed 's/^0*//'"`: run shell command `echo '0501234567' | sed 's/^0*//'` in an Apple script
- `echo '0501234567' | sed 's/^0*//'`: send the output of echo to the stream editor *sed* and do something with it
- `^0*`: regular expression: `^` = start of line `*` = quantifier- matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `'s/^0*//'`: `'s/reg_ex/replacement/'`: substitute the replacement string for the first instance of the regular expression in the pattern space. This means: replace as many leading zeros as possible with the replacement string *(=NIL/nothing)* = strip off leading zeros
- `set text1 to ...`: $text1=501234567
- `do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & text1`: `open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971501234567`

---

Both tested in 10.11.6 (El Capitan) only.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can explain how the second solution works exactly. It's perfect, but I don't know what it's doing

Comment: In this case, `quoted form of (the clipboard as string)` is actually `'0501234567'` not `"0501234567"`, as `quoted form` always uses _single quotes_. Not exactly sure why **Apple** did that, but probably to not allow _variable expansion_, or to avoid issues with _shell special characters_, or maybe it makes it easier for **AppleScript** to parse the `do shell script` _command_. Just guessing at logical reasons.

Comment: And that makes the whole difference between displaying the number in exponential form? Wow never knew that

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your *example* `0501234567` and your *expected* output `971501234567`, then I'm assuming all you are really trying to do is strip the first *character* from `0501234567`, of what's on the clipboard, and append `501234567` to the **URL** `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971` so that you have `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971501234567` as the **URL** for use with the `open` *command* in the `do shell script` *command*.

**If I'm understanding your need correctly, then simply this is all you need:**

```
do shell script ¬
    "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & ¬
    text 2 thru -1 of (the clipboard as text)
```

- <sup>Note that the use of the line continuation character `¬` is not necessary, I'm just using it so the whole command line shows without having to scroll.</sup>

The *phone number* e.g. `0501234567` on *the clipboard* after all is not a *real number* in the sense of an *integer* that *mathematical calculations* need to be performed on *it*, in this use case. It is simply a *text string* of *numeric characters* for the manner in which it needs to be used and should be expressly treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

## convertNumberToString

Apple's Mac Automation Scripting Guide contains the following code in the [Manipulating Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateNumbers.html) section titled **Converting a Long Number to a String**:

> In AppleScript, long numeric values are displayed in scientific notation. For example, `1234000000` is displayed by a script as `1.234E+9`. When this value is coerced to a string, it becomes: `"1.234E+9"`. The handler (below) in Listing 20-3 converts a number, regardless of length, to a string of numeric characters instead of a numeric string in scientific notation.

```
set myNumber to 1 - "0501234567" as real
set myResult to "971" & convertNumberToString(1 - myNumber)

-- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateNumbers.html
on convertNumberToString(theNumber)
    set theNumberString to theNumber as string
    set theOffset to offset of "E" in theNumberString
    if theOffset = 0 then return theNumberString
    set thePrefix to text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) of theNumberString
    set theConvertedNumberPrefix to ""
    if thePrefix begins with "-" then
        set theConvertedNumberPrefix to "-"
        if thePrefix = "-" then
            set thePrefix to ""
        else
            set thePrefix to text 2 thru -1 of thePrefix
        end if
    end if
    set theDecimalAdjustment to (text (theOffset + 1) thru -1 of theNumberString) as number
    set isNegativeDecimalAdjustment to theDecimalAdjustment is less than 0
    if isNegativeDecimalAdjustment then
        set thePrefix to (reverse of (characters of thePrefix)) as string
        set theDecimalAdjustment to -theDecimalAdjustment
    end if
    set theDecimalOffset to offset of "." in thePrefix
    if theDecimalOffset = 0 then
        set theFirstPart to ""
    else
        set theFirstPart to text 1 thru (theDecimalOffset - 1) of thePrefix
    end if
    set theSecondPart to text (theDecimalOffset + 1) thru -1 of thePrefix
    set theConvertedNumber to theFirstPart
    set theRepeatCount to theDecimalAdjustment
    if (length of theSecondPart) is greater than theRepeatCount then set theRepeatCount to length of theSecondPart
    repeat with a from 1 to theRepeatCount
        try
            set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & character a of theSecondPart
        on error
            set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "0"
        end try
        if a = theDecimalAdjustment and a is not equal to (length of theSecondPart) then set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "."
    end repeat
    if theConvertedNumber ends with "." then set theConvertedNumber to theConvertedNumber & "0"
    if isNegativeDecimalAdjustment then set theConvertedNumber to (reverse of (characters of theConvertedNumber)) as string
    return theConvertedNumberPrefix & theConvertedNumber
end convertNumberToString
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts a string to decimal integer, then back to a string. This eliminates any preceding zeros.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set text1 to the clipboard
    if false then -- set to true if you need whitespace removed.
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {space, tab, linefeed, return}
        set text1 to text items of text1
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}
        set text1 to text1 as string
    end if
    set text2 to "$((10#" & text1 & "))"
    do shell script "open https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971" & text2
    return input
end run

Example: 0501234567
Actual Output : 971501234567
```